# How can I defeat the final boss in Petz Dogs 2?

Tags: petz-dogs-2

How should I defeat the final boss in Petz Dogs 2 for the Wii? What equipment or food do I need to bring? I tried with jerky as a food but I constantly get knocked unconscious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Petz Dogs 2 final boss is named:[Ivlet.](http://petz.wikia.com/wiki/Ivlet)

In order to make sure you are ready to beat him, stock up on food:

1. Jerky
2. Biscuits

Make sure you have the maximum stack of 30 each. (Jerky costing 120pp and Biscuits costing 90pp).

Before you fight Ivlet you will be under attack by the chaotic dragon. The dragon is easy to kill. Both the dragon and Ivlet can be killed by throwing a stone at them and then doing the bark command. This deals 1 heart every time.